# Best way to draw smooth curve over points in cv2

Tags: python, opencv, spline

I have a set of points I would like to draw a nice smooth curve over (cv2, python). There is a lot of interpolations while working with graphs in python (cubic interpolation for instance), but it assumes that one of coordinates increasing. While in my case the points scattered over an image. Is there any spline like interpolation in OpenCV?

Here comes the points :

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: No, no spline in OpenCV.... but probably you'll find some package in Python to do this, like [scipy.interp2d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html)

Comment: Have you looked at [KalmanFilter](http://opencvexamples.blogspot.com/2014/01/kalman-filter-implementation-tracking.html)?